# Linker error LNK2019 on including SDL.h

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to get my program to allow me to use C++'s input and output streams for debugging purposes but it won't work?

My code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    cout << "I work!";

    return 0;
}
```

That is all I have and it won't work. I plan to use SDL to make a small checkers game but I'd like to use `<iostream>` to debug.

Here's my errors:

> ```
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main_utf8
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
> ```

Comment: Try adding `#undef main` after your `#include` directives. If that fixes the problem, the SDL header has `#define main something` in it, and you need to link against SDL libraries for things to link successfully.

Comment: That didn't fix it.

Comment: Well, you need to link against some SDL library. Their documentation should have that information, and Google can help you figure out how to link libraries in Visual Studio'

Comment: Nah I've already linked to that.

Comment: Are you linking against the old `SDL_main`? Shouldn't you link with `SDL2_main`?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered by [FAQ](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27SDL_main.27.22_...):

> Make sure that you are declaring main() as:
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])

Since `SDL_main` is not special name known to C++ compiler, it mangles it by general rules. SDL have forward declaration with correct linking flags (at least `extern "C"`) only for `int SDL_main(int, char**)`.